# YouTube Live Streaming API rate error: how to find out, which exactly quota is exceeded?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We develop a server application that publishes meetings from internal system into YouTube live events. It accesses API on behalf of its only user, the channel owner, and authenticates with both API key and OAuth 2.0 Client ID.

The code creates live events as described in the guide:

```py
broadcast = youtube.liveBroadcasts().insert(...).execute()
stream = youtube.liveStreams().insert(...).execute()
youtube.liveBroadcasts().bind(
    part='id,status', id=broadcast['id'], streamId=stream['id']
).execute()
```

After about 15-25 created live events YouTube Live Streaming API starts returning error `userRequestsExceedRateLimit`:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User requests exceed the rate limit.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "User requests exceed the rate limit.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "userRequestsExceedRateLimit"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After one day of waiting the very first request sent was rejected with the same error. The Quota page in console shows two failed requests, far from reaching any limits:

[image: screenshot of Google Cloud console Quota snippet]

How to find out which limit has been exceeded?

UPDATE 1: the quota did not reset on midnight west coast USA, the limit was active at least until 18:30 UTC next day (10:30 PST). Apparently, the quota was reset 24 hours after exceeding the limit.

Also, while calls to create live broadcasts were rejected with error, the calls for listing objects were working. It looks like there could be not a single "unit quota", but rather multiple quotas for different "domains".

UPDATE 2: the quota increase request was approved, and quota was increased, but that **did not change the limit** of live events that can be created per day. The API starts returning the same error after inserting 15-25 live broadcasts.

Again, when the API already started returning `userRequestsExceedRateLimit` for `liveBroadcasts().insert()`, other calls could still be sent: deleting all created events works, listing channel contents works, as if the quota was not reached at all.

Comment: Which request are you making please include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, done, the code added into beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is *user*.

> **User** requests exceed the rate limit.

You are using all your `Queries per minute per user`.

## cost based vs query based

The YouTube API doesn't work like the other apis, its cost based not query based.   [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

Yes the page says query based that's just because they didn't change the UI for a single api.

See: [Intro to YouTube API and Cost-Based Quota: Everything You Need to Know](https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc?si=puE-1mhW_wACKmpw)

It is not the number of calls it is the cost of your calls

Comment: That is hardly true, please read the question text -- we waited for one day not doing any requests, and the error still persisted.

Comment: You waited until midnight west coast USA time when the quote reset? 

Comment: But how did a single user make 180k queries (to get the error) whilst the `queries per day` only recorded 2 of them?

Comment: @Tigerrrrr they cant they will be blocked by the 10k project quota

Comment: My confusion lies in their screenshot, which only shows "2" under "current usage" for `queries per day` (the project quota)

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, yes, I waited for about a day, definitely after PST midnight. The quota was reset apparently at 24 hours after exceeding.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr, that is a strange thing: the quota page surely shows number of calls, not units. Also the quota extension form requires to describe usage in terms of calls / queries:

Justification for requesting additional quota? * Provide a detailed breakdown:
...
- Daily usage pattern (total number of calls and peak QPS)
- Expected number of calls

Comment: @void the YouTube API doesn't work like the other apis, its cost based not query based.   [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)  Yes the page says query based thats just becouse they didnt change the ui for a single api.    [Intro to YouTube API and Cost-Based Quota: Everything You Need to Know](https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc?si=puE-1mhW_wACKmpw)  It is not the number of calls it is the cost of your calls

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, the clue about outdated Quota page is good. Please see the update, increasing quota did not raise the actual limit, it remained the same 15-25 new live events per day.