# Please explain the YouTube Data API's Quota / Limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I simply have a couple queries about the YouTube Data API which for some reason I just can not find any answers to. Even if the answer was explained clearly in the documentation, I hope to keep this StackOverflow question up so it can possibly help other people who, like me, also missed it in the documentation.

To help understand my two questions, here's an image that states the quotas for the YouTube Data API:

[image: the quotas for the YouTube Data API]

1. My first question: How is it possible that the limit for `queries per minute` is 1.6m and the `queries per day` limit is 10k?

   Surely `queries per minute` can never go above 10,000? I mean, I guess if you send 10k queries in 30 seconds from 23:59:30 and then do another 10k before 00:00:30... but that's still only 20k out of the 1.6m limit provided).
2. How do I make use of `queries per minute per user`?

   All the API calls I make go directly to `queries per day` and
   `queries per minute`.

   My usual "method" of an API call is to first request scopes and then call the API with the received access token, as instructed by [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#userconsentprompt).

If you could help me with this, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> My first question: How is it possible that the limit for queries per minute is 1.6m and the queries per day limit is 10k?

> Surely queries per minute can never go above 10,000? I mean, I guess if you send 10k queries in 30 seconds from 23:59:30 and then do another 10k before 00:00:30... but that's still only 20k out of the 1.6m limit provided).

About ten years ago the default development quota was around 1 million quota points.  They had to reduce it to 10k to prevent spam.

Queries per day can be extended the other quotas can not.  I guess it just made sence to leave them as they were.

> How do I make use of queries per minute per user?

> All the API calls I make go directly to queries per day and queries per minute.

> My usual "method" of an API call is to first request scopes and then call the API with the received access token, as instructed by Google's documentation.

Queries per day is a project based quota all the users on your system use that.  So if you have ten users they are using the "queries per minute per user" and they all lump up to use the Queries per day.

Remember the 10k is just a development quota you can apply for an extension when every you like.

I have a video on this as well [Intro to YouTube API and Cost-Based Quota: Everything You Need to Know](https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc?si=gHn0c19J9MwitJ-O)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at numerous answers on SO on somewhat related questions, I think I have a general idea of the answer to both my questions.

1. "How is it possible that the limit for `queries per minute` is 1.6m and the `queries per day` limit is 10k?"

   It seems the answer here is simply that it's not expected to be possible that the `queries per minute` ever reach above 10k in a single minute, and therefore it's also not expected that the `queries per minute` reach the allotted 1.6 million.

   However, the secret sauce to this pie of confusion is the fact that you can't change the `queries per minute` (or `queries per minute, per user`) but you certainly can change the `queries per day` (by [direct request to Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)).

   What this means is both `queries per minute` and `queries per minute per user` are pretty much useless to you until you request a high enough `queries per day` limit for it to even matter. For now, you can imagine your `queries per minute` and `queries per minute per user` are equal to the `queries per day` (which is likely 10,000) until your `queries per day` exceeds that actual quota for the other two.

   As discovered in the comments of this answer, when the documentation states "10,000 units per day, an amount sufficient for the majority of our API users" they are explicitly referring to "in the development phase".

   Google expects all API users to request an increased `queries per day` quota after development is finished. Therefore, that "10k" will become a couple of million (assuming your request is approved) which would therefore make the `queries per minute` and `queries per minute per user` matter a lot more.
2. "How do I make use of queries per minute per user?"

   It seems the answer to this question is: "You already are". As in, you already are using `queries per minute per user` but Google just doesn't tell you... Originally, when I asked the question, and I assume others had the same thought that the `-` meant that no "user" had made a request. As in, somehow the project was making all the API calls on behalf of the user... rather than the user making the API calls themselves, and therefore it wouldn't count as `per user`.

   But that's not the case, it seems that Google does count it as `per user` but simply just hides the information from you.

   I only indirectly figured that one out [thanks to Linda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539020/11224924) and the image the OP posted.

<s>I'm not going to mark this as the answer since I'm not confident it's actually all correct and there's an inconsistency with the 2nd answer.</s> This was confirmed by [Linda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552056/11224924).

Comment: queries per minute and queries per minute per user are not useless they prevent flooding of the api.    queries per minute per user is denoted by the user who has authorized the application.   If john floods the app john will be blocked but if jane doesnt she can keep going.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo | But John can't even make 160k requests, because by that time the project itself is well over its 10k limit. Therefore blocking anyone (including Jane) to keep going.

Comment: No john can not on the development quota he and jane will be limited to 10k shared.   Remember this is a Development / testing quota.  You are NOT expected to use this in production. apply for an extension.

Comment: Ah. I wish https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits mentioned that at least once: "You are not expected to use 10k quota in production".

Comment: so you want **Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day, an amount sufficient for the majority of our API users.**  Okay i guess i can agree that could be worded better.  Let me see if i can find someone to email about that.

Comment: Much appreciated. Explicitly, worded better to make it clear that "our API users" refers to "our API users in the development/testing phase" or something along those lines. As to me at least, it implies that only big companies with millions of concurrent users (the minority) would ever request over 10k queries per day.